# Symfony2 self referencing form theme errors

Tags: forms, symfony

I've created a simple form:

```
{% form_theme offer_form _self %}
{{ form_start(offer_form) }}
<table id="offer-form" title="{{ 'Offer'|trans }}">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_label(offer_form.offernumber) }}: {{ form_errors(offer_form.offernumber) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>{{ form_widget(offer_form.offernumber) }}</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{{ form_end(offer_form) }}

{% block form_errors %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if errors|length > 0 %}
            {% for error in errors %}
                <span class="form-error">{{ error.message }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

But on rendering I get following error:

> Variable "errors" does not exist...

It only happens when I self reference the form, when I use external file it works fine, but I would like to keep form and errors block customization in same file, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try put the block form_errors before the form theme line?

Comment: @sepikas_antanas I'm having this error too and can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Did you solve it?

Comment: @PLPeeters no, I did not found a solution, I just used external files for my forms.

Comment: @sepikas_antanas I ended up solving it that way too. I don't get how it changes anything to have the theme in an external file though...

Answer (score 6):

Try changing this

```
{% if errors|length > 0 %}
```

to this

```
{% if errors is defined and errors|length > 0 %}
```

That did it for me.